# Unable to fetch custom field data from cart page to checkout page for orders in woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have created some custom text fields to add to name field and custom message fields in cart page.So once user goes to cart page if he fills the data and click on proceed to checkout those data should be displayed in checkout page and once the customer place the order those custom fields data should be stored in orders page in admin as well.

As of now for order notes it is working fine and the field To is not working.Here is the code which i have tired.It i displaying only To as a heading in the admin panel But not displaying the name in to field in admin panel.

```
// Add the order_comments field to the cart
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_collaterals', 'order_comments_custom_cart_field' );
function order_comments_custom_cart_field() {
?>
<div class="customer_notes_on_cart" style="clear:both;">
<?php
woocommerce_form_field('to_notes_text', array(
    'placeholder'   => __('To'),
    'class' => array('form-row-last'),
    'clear' => true,
), ''); 
?></div><?php
 }
 // PHP: Remove "(optional)" from non required fields
 add_filter( 'woocommerce_form_field' , 'remove_checkout_optional_fields_label', 10, 4 );
function remove_checkout_optional_fields_label( $field, $key, $args, $value ) {
// Only on cart page
if( is_cart() ) {
    $optional = '&nbsp;<span class="optional">(' . esc_html__( 'optional', 'woocommerce' ) . ')</span>';
    $field = str_replace( $optional, '', $field );
}
return $field;
}
// Process the checkout and overwriting the normal button
 add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'change_proceed_to_checkout', 15 );
function change_proceed_to_checkout() {
remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );

?>
<form id="checkout_form" method="POST" action="<?php echo wc_get_checkout_url(); ?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="to_notes" id="to_notes" value="">        
    <button type="submit" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward" style="width:100%;"><?php
    esc_html_e( 'Proceed to checkout', 'woocommerce' ) ?></button>
</form>
<?php
 }
  // Jquery script for cart and checkout pages
 add_action('wp_footer', 'customer_notes_jquery' );
 function customer_notes_jquery() {
?>
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    <?php // For cart
        if( is_cart() ) : ?>            
        $('#to_notes_text').on( 'blur', function(){
            $('#to_notes').val($(this).val());
        });

    <?php // For checkout
        elseif( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) : ?>
        $('#to_comments' ).val("<?php echo sanitize_text_field($_POST['to_notes']); ?>");           
    <?php endif; ?>
});
</script>
<?php
}
/**
* Update the order meta with field value
*/
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 
'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
?>
<?php
if ( ! empty( $_POST['to_notes_text'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'To', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['to_notes_text'] ) );
}
}
/**
  * Display field value on the order edit page
 */
  add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
  function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    ?>
<?php
echo '<p><strong>'.__('TO').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'TO', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: Anyone who can suggest me how to do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by doing in this way

```
/**
* Update the order meta with field value
**/ 
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 
'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
?>
<?php
if ( ! empty( $_POST['from_comments'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'FROM', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['from_comments'] 
 ) );
}   
}
/**
* Update the order meta with field value
**/ 
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 
'my_customs_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );
 function my_customs_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
?>
<?php
if ( ! empty( $_POST['to_comments'] ) ) {
    update_post_meta( $order_id, 'TO', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['to_comments'] ) 
  );
   }    
   }
   /**
   * Display field value on the order edit page
   **/
   add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 
 'my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );

 function my_custom_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
?>
<?php
echo '<p><strong>'.__('FROM').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'FROM', true 
  ) . '</p>';
 echo '<p><strong>'.__('TO').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'TO', true ) 
 . '</p>';
  }
 /**
 * Add the field to the checkout
 */
 add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'my_custom_checkout_field' );

 function my_custom_checkout_field( $checkout ) {
 ?>
 <?php
  echo '<div id="my_custom_checkout_field"><h2>' . __('TO ') . '</h2>';
  woocommerce_form_field( 'from_comments', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'placeholder'   => __('FROM'),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'from_comments' ));

   woocommerce_form_field( 'to_comments', array(
    'type'          => 'text',
    'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
    'placeholder'   => __('TO'),
    ), $checkout->get_value( 'to_comments' ));
       echo '</div>';
        }
```